# Best way to build checkbox filter to show/hide elements based on multiple data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filter, filtering

I'm trying to build a checkbox filter that will show/hide elements based on multiple data-* attributes on those elements.  I've made a couple attempts which aren't quite working out to the filtering I want.

I've made a bare bones fiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ez8o1ra/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var $checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var $productItem = $('.productItem');

    if ($checked.length > 0) {
        $productItem.hide();

        $checked.each(function() {
            $('.productItem[data-level=' + this.value + ']').show();
            $('.productItem[data-price=' + this.value + ']').show();
            $('.productItem[data-network=' + this.value + ']').show();
        });
    } else {
        $productItem.show();
    }
});
```

I know this code is not correct, it's just where I hit the same wall starting over from scratch in a fiddle.

The filtering I'm after is an "and" filter where the more filters you apply, the less results you typically end up with.

For example, in the fiddle, if you select "gold" you just get gold results. If you add the "silver" filter you get gold and silver, which is good so far. So I'm and'ing fine within one data-* attribute.

The problem is if you add another data-* filter, for example, with gold and silver selected, add the "network A" filter. In this case, I want the results to be filtered down to **only** gold and **only** silver elements with **only** gold/silver elements that also have the network A data attribute.

What's the best way to build this sort of filtering so when the price filter is applied it filters results down even more?

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to add the relevant html?

Comment: I'm not sure I have a full understanding of your goal, but if it helps; you know you can chain selectors on a single element, right? ie, `$('.productItem[data-level=3][data-price=4].activeProductItem:focus:last-child[data-network=att]')`. It gets hard to read without spaces, but you can actually apply many selectors, be they of the same type or others, to a single element

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle for the full code. The only reason I put any code here is because stackoverflow enforces this with any fiddle links. It seems dumb to duplicate all the code here when the fiddle has it all in an executable format.

Comment: With a reputation over 200 (as I write) you should be familiar enough with the site to appreciate that we request that the code be posted here in order that when (or if) an external site fails, dies, reorganises or if you yourself delete your Fiddle, the question remains understandable and relevant to future visitors. If nothing else the lack of "[MCVE]" code renders your question "off-topic."

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic shell of what you will want to do

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var $checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var $items = $('.productItem');
    var filters = {};

    if ($checked.length) {
        $('.productItem').hide();

        $checked.each(function() {
           filters[$(this).data('filter-type')] = $(this).val();
        });

        $items.each(function(i) {
            for (var key in filters) {
                if ($(this).data(key) == filters[key]) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.productItem').show();
    }
});
```

Let me see if I can explain this in a simple way. What you are trying to accomplish is essentially a mapping of filters to a list of products. For every filter, only show the products that match the filter(s). To accomplish this, I stored the filters as they are selected as key/value pairs. They key of the filter is the filter type (level, price, or network) and to store the filter type I added a data attribute, `data-filter-type` to each checkbox. So, for checkboxes with the filter type of level, the attribute would be `data-filter-type="level"`. Coupled with your existing `value` attribute, filters can be represented neatly in the JavaScript as key/value pairs:

```
data-filter-type: value
```

So, when the user selects filters "platinum" and "network A", the filters associative array would look like:

```
{
    level: platinum,
    network: networkA
}
```

Now a basic loop can be ran through the filters array and target all of the items that contain either of those filters. Due to the lack of clarity on your question, I assumed you want an `or` relationship, meaning only one of the filters need to apply to the item. If you need all selected filters to apply to each item, you will need to modify the code accordingly.

Another problem with this code is when the filters are added to the filter array:

```
filters[$(this).data('filter-type')] = $(this).val();
```

This will only work if each filter is unique, that is, only one of each filter is checked. If two *level* filters are checked, for instance, only the second one will apply, because the key will be overwritten. You will need to modify that part to store both values under the same key. A basic array of values for each key would do the job.

As I said, this is a minimal example. There are sure to be more cases you will need to fix, but the general steps I have outlined are a good starting point for you. Good luck!

Almost forgot about the fiddle link! http://jsfiddle.net/7ez8o1ra/3/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add an extra attribute to your checkboxes to explicitly define top-level filters for your $productItem, before you apply subsequent criteria. I also changed your UI. Hiding the filtered cards seems like punitive UX to your end-users, so graying out cards (with a CSS opacity style) seems to flow better, but maybe that's just me...

```
<input type="checkbox" data-type="level" value="platinum" /> ...
<input type="checkbox" data-type="price" value="0-2" /> ...
<input type="checkbox" data-type="network" value="networkA" /> ...
```

....

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var $checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    var $productItem = $('.productItem');
    var filters = [];
    var productFilter = '';

    if ($checked.length > 0) {
        $productItem.css('opacity',0.25);

        $checked.each(function() {
           dataType = $(this).attr('data-type');
           if (!filters[dataType]) filters[dataType] = [];  
           filters[dataType].push(this.value);
        });

        for(var filterType in filters) { 
            for (i in filters[filterType]) {
                productFilter += '[data-'+filterType+'="'+filters[filterType][i]+'"],';
            }
            productFilter = productFilter.replace(/,$/,'');
        }
        $productItem
            .filter(productFilter)
            .map(function() {
                $(this).css('opacity',1);
            });
    } else {
        $productItem.css('opacity',1);
    }
});
```

Please see a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ez8o1ra/35/

Comment: The filtering isn't based on having a level, though. For example, you should be able to start filtering anywhere, like initially checking network C and have the results filtered down to only show network C. Then add another filter and have the results further refined to only show network C and the additional filter

Comment: Ah, okay. It's actually not hard to do what you want (I think, if I'm understanding your requirements correctly). By adding a "data-type" attribute to all checkboxes and then creating a multiple attribute filter, you can constrain and filter based upon cascading criteria...I've updated my answer above.

Comment: This is close but the checkboxes in each filter category/facet/row are acting like radio buttons. For example, if you check gold **and** silver you should get all cards decorated with gold **and** silver attributes. If you then add a $0-2000 filter you should be filtered down to all gold 0-2 cards **and** silver 0-2 cards. Selecting one filter (max) in each filter category/facet/row looks to be working great, though.

Comment: Now we're getting into questions of usability and what I would call a "paradox of mutual exclusivity". I would recommend either creating a better UI to explicitly cue users as to a common sense decision tree (select level first, then..), or use opacity to gray out selections which don't conform to a boolean OR logic that I outlined above...check out this fiddle, which is considerably more polite to your users: https://jsfiddle.net/7ez8o1ra/27/

Comment: It should be AND logic - the filters selected should apply to each card, not across all cards, if that makes sense. For example, I select gold and I see just gold cards. This is correct. I add $2,000-$4,000 to that and I should not see anything because I'm filtering down to "gold 2-4" cards of which there are no cards with those attributes. I'm seeing two "gold 0-2" cards and a "silver 2-4" and "bronze 2-4". So the filter is show me "gold" cards OR "2-4" cards. It should be show me gold cards which are also 2-4 cards, i.e., show me "gold 02" cards.

Comment: Gotcha. This is the best I can offer: https://jsfiddle.net/7ez8o1ra/34/ ... will update answer above to match.

Comment: Thanks, it's better but still breaks down as you add filters. If you do a gold and silver and $2,000-$4000 you should only see the "silver 2-4" card because there are no "gold 2-4" cards (you see two "gold 0-2" cards). I've got another version where I loop through each card, extract the data-*attrs into vars, then loop through the selected checkboxes and set a matched flag if appropriate.  I can get it to work with multiple selections in one filter facet or one filter selection across multiple filter facets, but can't seem to get the magic combination of filter selections working.