# How do I change column style of grid using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What changes should I make in JTML and Javascript.

```js
var opac;
function checkfun()
{
opac=(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'))
                          .filter((checkbox)=>checkbox.checked)
                        .map((checkbox)=>checkbox.value));
}
```

```css
body
{
    display: flex;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}


.form
{
    width: 15vw;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.mySidebar
{
    height: 500px;
    display: block;  
}

.mySidebar ul
{
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
}
.mySidebar li
{
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
    list-style: none;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.color-block
{
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 70vw;
    display: block;
}

.col-sm-4
{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.data-grid
{
    border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-height: auto;
    display: block;
}
/*-----------------colors-----------------*/
.red{
    background: red;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.blue{
    background: blue;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.green{
    background: green;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.yellow{
    background: yellow;
    widows: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Sidebar/menu -->
<div class="form">
    <div class="mySidebar">
  
        <div >
            <ul >Colours
                <li><input type="checkbox"  name="a" value="Red"   onclick="checkfun()"> Red</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"  name="a" value="Blue" onclick="checkfun()"> Blue</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"  name="a" value="Green"  onclick="checkfun()"> Green</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox"  name="a" value="Yellow"      onclick="checkfun()"> Yellow</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>Color Value
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="5" onclick="checkfun()"> 5</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="6" onclick="checkfun()"> 6</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Sidebar/menu -->
<div class="color-block">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="data-grid">
                <div class="red">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="data-grid">
                <div class="blue">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="data-grid">
                <div class="green">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="data-grid">
                <div class="yellow">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the link to a codepen: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/vishalkank/pen/exPKNW)

When I click on a checkbox, then only the matching criteria should be opaque and the others should be transparent.
That is if I click on Red then only the red color grid column should be opaque and other colors transparent.

Please help.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Doesn’t look like you even attempted to implement anything in this regard yet, which would make this question rather too broad to begin with. My suggestion would be that you go and find yourself some tutorials that explain how to build an element filter based on checkboxes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402030/best-way-to-build-checkbox-filter-to-show-hide-elements-based-on-multiple-data

Answer (score 0):

if you have any questions about the code feel free to ask :)

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
    var box = document.getElementById(e.target.value);
      if(e.target.checked)
        box.style.display = ''
      else
        box.style.display= "none"
    }))
```

```css
.box{
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em
}

#red{
    background: red
}

#green{
    background: green
}
```

```html
<li><input type="checkbox" value="red" checked>Red</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="green" checked>Green</li>

<div>
  <div class="box" id="red"></div>
  <div class="box" id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OPs and future researchers should not have to ask how your solution works.  You are expected to explain how your solution works and why it is a good idea.

Comment: Chuck in a bit of commenting & this would help :)